# Can I still claim my Hong Kong-based MPF pension if I move elsewhere?

Tags: retirement, savings, pension, hong-kong, mpf

I am 60 year old and I will not be living in hong kong in the future, would I still be able to claim back my mpf?

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**, if you are permanently departing from Hong Kong proof of permission to reside permanently elsewhere must be produced and such permanent departure can only be used as a ground for withdrawal once in a persons lifetime.